# Can you run a task multiple times with different system parameters in gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

So I have a project where I want to run a task multiple times with a different value for a system parameter each time, however I can't seem to do that short of calling gradle multiple times in a bash script which is not desirable. I tried `./gradlew myTask -Dproperty="value1" myTask -Dproperty="value2"` which ran myTask twice, which was good, but it ran with `property=value2` both times. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: I should also mention that I do not know value1 and value2 until buildtime. So I can't hardcore them into the build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following approach:

```
task executeTaskTwiceWithParameters {
    String[] propertyValues = System.getProperty("propertyValues" ,"").split(",")
    dependsOn propertyValues.collect { "runWith$it" }
    propertyValues.each { value ->
        task "runWith$value"(type: GradleBuild) {
            buildFile = 'build.gradle'
            tasks = ['doSomething']
            startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs += [property: value]
        }
    }
}

task doSomething {
    doLast {
        println System.getProperty("property")
    }
}
```

When invoked like

```
./gradlew executeTaskTwiceWithParameters -DpropertyValues=value1,value2
```

for each property value it launches an auxiliary gradle build to execute a task with this property value set. The same trick works for project properties as well.

Comment: I forgot the mention that I don't know what value1 and value2 are before runtime. So I can't just hardcore the values into the task. I will edit my question.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be a problem either. See updated answer for a fully dynamic example.

Comment: This doesn't work. The actual output is `value2` both times

Comment: Just to clarify this does not work for Gradle 5 but works for 4

Answer (score -1):

It will help you to think about the task as an 'instance' instead of 'type'. Then you would not have this  question. 
I suggest you to create another task of the same type and bind it to its arguments.

Comment: I forgot the mention that I don't know what value1 and value2 are before runtime. So I can't just hardcore the values into the task. I will edit my question.